# Travel insurance for someone residing in UK under biometric residence permit

Tags: insurance

I am an American citizen residing in the UK under a biometric residence permit. My husband is a UK citizen and I have a national insurance number. Wondering if i need a special type of travel insurance to visit the US for a week or if any company will cover me?

Comment: Nobody knows if your company will cover you.  Generally speaking however, it's best to get the same travel insurance your husband has.

Comment: @pnuts, yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any form of health insurance coverage is legally required to enter the US as a US citizen or, in most cases, as an alien so you don't absolutely *need* anything special.

The NHS has some information on [healthcare abroad](http://www.nhs.uk/nhsengland/Healthcareabroad/pages/Healthcareabroad.aspx) and a list of countries with which it has [an agreement](http://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/Healthcareabroad/countryguide/NonEEAcountries/Pages/Non-EEAcountries.aspx) but, unsurprisingly given the local healthcare system, the US is not one of them. This means that if you want to be covered, you will need a private travel insurance policy. Since you are a resident, I think most UK-based travel insurance should cover you as well but reading the fine print is always a good idea (see comments).

Comment: There are some US Visa categories which require the holder to obtain health insurance for the US for the duration of the stay, though. So the first sentence of the answer does not always hold for aliens. Surely that is not of relevance in this case.

Comment: Also it should be added that travel insurances sometimes do not have coverage in the country of nationality of the insured person, so the fine print of the travel insurance should be read.

Comment: @DCTLib Thanks for your comments! If you have more details (like a list of US visas which require health insurance), I am happy to edit my answer further. Alternatively, don't hesitate to write a better answer yourself (feel free to build upon mine, I would probably delete it afterwards)!